# Run Bat As Admin in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, administrator

I'm running the following from an elevated PowerShell session:

`Start-Process .\file.bat -Verb RunAs -Wait`

It's opening the bat file, but it's not doing it as administrator.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This definitely _should_ run with elevation (with administrative privileges), and does in my tests. What makes you suspect that it doesn't?

Comment: If your PowerShell session is already elevated, the batch file will inherit the elevation too. That means you should not need to use `-Verb RunAs`.

Comment: The simplest way to check if the batch file in running elevated is to put a command like ```%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query HKU\S-1-5-19``` into it, and check the result.

Comment: @Compo: Alternatively:`net session`

Comment: Assuming you're instructing me to put these in a bat file?  So for  ````net session```` I get ````There are no entries in the list.````  For ````%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query HKU\S-1-5-19````  I get ````HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\AppEvents
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Console
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Control Panel
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Environment
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\EUDC
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Keyboard Layout
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Network
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Software
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\System````.  As far as what makes me suspect that it's not running as admin - 1) it doesn't say ````Administrator````

Comment: and 2) it's not able to edit the files I'm trying to edit the way it does if I just right click the bat file and run it as admin.

Answer (score 1):

- **Child processes launched *from an elevated process* are themselves elevated**.

  - Given that you're running from an elevated PowerShell process, as you state, you can **simply invoke the batch file *directly***, in the *current* console window, which has the following advantages:

    - Execution is (by default and invariably) *synchronous*.
    - You can capture (or silence) the batch file's output, if any
    - Its exit code is reflected in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode):

      ```
      # From an already elevated session, invoking a batch file will run 
      # it elevated too.
      .\file.bat
      ```
  - If you do want to run it in a *separate window*, you can use your original command (the `-Verb RunAs` is then *implied* and may be omitted; *no* UAC dialog is displayed either way).
- When **running from a *non-elevated* session**, your **[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) `-Verb RunAs`** approach ***is* needed**, and the elevated `cmd.exe` process that runs the batch file **of necessity runs in a *new window***.

  - ***Caveat* re *working directory* when creating an elevated `cmd.exe` process** (whether directly, with `-FilePath cmd.exe`, or indirectly with, e.g. `-FilePath .\file.bat`) or a **`powershell.exe` process (Windows PowerShell)**:

    - The elevated process' **working directory will *invariably* be `C:\Windows\System32`**, irrespective of the caller's working directory, and irrespective of any `-WorkingDirectory` argument, which is *ignored*.
  - Other executables - notably including `pwsh.exe`, the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI - *do* inherit the caller's working directory.

---

In other words:

- **Your approach can be simplified, but it *should work***.

  - If you unexpectedly aren't permitted to perform an operation in the elevated session, the problem must be *unrelated* to elevation; notably, files and folders may have ACLs that even administrators aren't allowed to access or modify.
  - Also note the working-directory caveat discussed above.
- A s**imple way to verify whether a batch file is indeed run in an *elevated* process** is to add the following to it (relying on the fact that `net session` can only be invoked successfully from an *elevated* process):

  ```
   net session >NUL 2>&1 && echo ELEVATED || echo NON-elevated
  ```
- Note that **whether or not the title bar of the new window starts with `Administrator:`  is *not* a reliable indicator of whether the session is elevated**.

  - Notably, *direct invocation* of a batch file with `Start-Process -Verb RunAs` does *not* cause the title prefix to be appear, even though the resulting `cmd.exe` process *is* elevated (use the command above to  verify).
  - Only if you call *via `cmd.exe`* do you see the prefix, which you can do as follows (but note that it makes no *functional* difference):

    ```
    # Note: The batch file's *full path* must be passed, because 
    #       the elevated process' working dir will be C:\Windows\System32 
    #       if the caller is non-elevated.
    Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd.exe "/c `"$(Convert-Path .\file.bat)`""
    ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{   
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process "$psHome\powershell.exe" -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments

break
}

Start-Process .\file.bat -Verb RunAs -Wait
```

If the script runs without administrative privileges the elevation form will be shown. After the user clicked Yes on the popup, your file will be reopened with Admin rights

Comment: `Start-Process .\file.bat -Verb RunAs -Wait` should and does work as-is, so there is no reason for a workaround via self-elevation of the PowerShell script. Note that the premise is "I'm running the following from an elevated PowerShell session", in which case there's no need for `Start-Process -Verb RunAs` at all - direct invocation of `.\file.bat` will run with elevation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I couldn't get anything to run as admin when opening a new window.  I didn't realize I could just run it within the same PowerShell session, so I changed it to just running:

`.\file.bat`

and that is getting me what I need.

Comment: You beat me to it. Indeed, direct invocation is the best solution in your scenario (when already running in an elevated session). My answer also addresses your `net session` question and the fact that the absence of an `Administrator:` prefix in the title bar does _not_ necessarily mean that the process is _not_ elevated.